# Longest word where each prefix is another word

Tags: wordplay, optimization

What is the longest English word, e.g. “someword” where “s”, “so”, “som”… “someword” are all also valid English words?

The longest such word I could come up with is 6 letters:

> antics

Can you do better?

Comment: Can you please specify which dictionary is to be used? Please see Meta's [What is a valid English word?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6111/what-is-a-valid-english-word) and [others](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=valid+dictionary).

Answer (score 4):

If we consider standard English words that would appear in a Scrabble dictionary, the maximum seems to be

> SEVEN
>  I found 4 of them: ABASERS, AMIDOLS, AMUSERS, and ANTICKS

If we expand this to words, acronyms, names, and abbreviations used in English, this becomes open ended and arbitrary, however I did find one (and only one) decent candidate of length

> TEN: MACHINERYS
>  M: English abbreviation for meter, 1000 in Roman Numerals, the letter M itself, etc.
>  MA: Synonym for mom
>  MAC: Type of computer
>  MACH: A speed
>  MACHI: A shaman (valid in WordFued, e.g.)
>  MACHIN: [An animal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/machin)
>  MACHINE
>  MACHINER: One who works a machine
>  MACHINERY
>  MACHINERYS (MACHINERY'S)  [Possessive form of MACHINERY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machinery%27s_Handbook)

Answer (score 1):

Using [this word list,](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words) I can find twenty-five words of length

> **nine.**
>  To get an idea of how much this word list contains, of those twenty-five words, only ISMTHIANS begins with a vowel!

If you prefer, we can instead

> back down to length eight, which has words like the much-more-reasonable AM[E](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ame)ND[E](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/french-english/amende)RS.

Comment: But one of the sub-words isn't a *"valid English word"*. Merriam-Webster lists it but only as part of a borrowed French phrase. Those word lists are the result of trawling.

Comment: From the links you provide, AME is an abbreviation and AMENDE is a French word. The question specifically requires valid English words.